# Tying in Object pages to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, es6-class

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I keep getting a 404 message. Here is my code.

**index.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drones</title>
    <script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader-dev.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script>
          System.import('src/app.js');
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
import {Car} from './car.js';
import {Drone} from './drones.js';

let c = new Car();
let d = new Drone();

console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

**Vehicle.js**

```
export class Vehicle {


}
```

**drones.js**

```
import Vehicle from 'vehicle.js';

export class Drone extends Vehicle {

}
```

**car.js**

```
import {Vehicle} from 'vehicle.js';

export class Car extends Vehicle {

}
```

[image: 404 message I keep getting]

Comment: Are `car.js` and `drones.js` in the same directory as `app.js`? If so, do they have the same permissions as `app.js`?

Comment: car.js and drones.js are not in the same directory as app.js. They are in /src/classes while app.js is in src

Answer (score 0):

Import the app.js with a `<script type=“module“ src=“src/app.js“></script>` in the html and make sure you declare the relative path to the js files you import

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, if `car.js` and `drones.js` in a subdirectory of the directory `app.js` resides in, then you'll want to change your imports to either:

```
// use relative pathing
import {Car} from './classes/car.js';
import {Drone} from './classes/drones.js';
```

or to:

```
// use absolute pathing
import {Car} from 'src/classes/car.js';
import {Drone} from 'src/classes/drones.js';
```

This is because the `./` part of the path points to whatever directory the referencing file resides in (i.e., `./` in `src/app.js` points to `src/`.